# Profiling a webapp on JBoss 7 with JVisualVM

Tags: web-applications, profiling, jboss7.x, jvisualvm

I would like to profile my webapp with JVisualVM on JBoss 7.

So I launch that tool, and open the JVM running JBoss.

I click on "Profiler", "Settings" and in "CPU settings" I put that :

- "Start profiling from classes:" : com.mycompany.myapp.action.**
- Profile new Runnables
- "Profile only classes:" : com.mycompany.*

And when I click on "CPU" (to profile CPU), in JBoss I've got :

```
Profiler Agent: 250 classes cached.
Profiler Agent: Redefining 100 classes at idx 0, out of total 188 
Profiler Agent: Redefining 88 classes at idx 100, out of total 188 
10:26:05,720 ERROR [stderr] (server-timer1) Exception in thread "server-timer1" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/netbeans/lib/profiler/server/ProfilerRuntimeCPUFullInstr
10:26:05,721 ERROR [stderr] (server-timer1)     at org.jboss.sun.net.httpserver.ServerImpl$ServerTimerTask1.run(ServerImpl.java:895)
10:26:05,722 ERROR [stderr] (server-timer1)     at java.util.TimerThread.mainLoop(Timer.java:534)
10:26:05,722 ERROR [stderr] (server-timer1)     at java.util.TimerThread.run(Timer.java:484)
```

By googling, it seems I must [add `jfluid-server.jar`](http://i-proving.com/2011/07/07/how-to-get-visualvm-to-profile-jboss-without-crashing/) in the JBoss classpath but when I do that with Eclipse, the jar disappears before I re-launch the server...

Others advice to [launch VisualVM with a classpath containing JBoss modules' jar](https://community.jboss.org/message/766276), but I still have the errors in the JBoss AS.

Is there a configuration in `standalone.xml` in order to add that jar to JBoss 7 classpath ?

Thanks !

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Adding `-Djboss.modules.system.pkgs=org.netbeans.lib.profiler.server` to the JVM arguments seems to avoid that exception. Seen on https://issues.jboss.org/browse/JBAS-8927.